# Select object with largest JSON key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Given a table called `test` with the following definition

```
 Column | Type | Modifiers
--------+------+-----------
 a      | json |
```

where every row has some JSON in a form similar to

```
{
  "1": "abc",
  "2": "def",
  "3": "ghi" 
}
```

how can I make a query that selects the value with the largest key? (in this example you'd choose `"ghi"` since it's key, `3`, is the largest)

---

The way I conceptualize it, ideally it'd be a query like this:

```
SELECT a->max(json_object_keys(a)) from test;
```

but obviously that doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to tackle the problem incrementally:

```
tometzky=> select * from json_object_keys('{"1": "abc","2": "def","3": "ghi"}'::json) as k;
 k 
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)

tometzky=> select max(k) from json_object_keys('{"1": "abc","2": "def","3": "ghi"}'::json) as k;
 max 
-----
 3
(1 row)

tometzky=> create temporary table test (a json);
tometzky=> insert into test values('{
  "1": "abc",
  "2": "def",
  "3": "ghi" 
}');
tometzky=> insert into test values('{
  "100": "jkl",
  "20": "kmo",
  "3": "pqr" 
}');

tometzky=> select (select max(k) from json_object_keys(a) as k) from test;
 max 
-----
 3
 3
(2 rows)

tometzky=> select (select max(k::int) from json_object_keys(a) as k) from test;
 max 
-----
   3
 100
(2 rows)
```

So the answer is:

```
tometzky=> select a->(select max(k::int)::text from json_object_keys(a) as k) from test;
 ?column? 
----------
 "ghi"
 "jkl"
(2 rows)
```

I assume that "value with the largest key" is for each row, as it does not look like a well defined problem otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `json_each` like this:

```
select   value 
from     (  select (json_each(a)).* 
            from   test
         ) keyval
order by key::int desc
limit    1;
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/AIGU77929)